# AttributeError: Cutoff time DataFrame must contain a column with either the same name as the target dataframe index or a column named "instance_id"

Tags: python, deep-learning, feature-engineering, featuretools

I'm learning how to use Featuretools with this [tutorial](https://github.com/Featuretools/predict-remaining-useful-life/blob/master/Advanced%20Featuretools%20RUL.ipynb) and I've made it to a snippet which is right below this paragraph:

```py
from featuretools.tsfresh import CidCe
import featuretools as ft

fm, features = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_dataframe_name='RUL data',
    agg_primitives=['last', 'max'],
    trans_primitives=[],
    chunk_size=.26,
    cutoff_time=cutoff_time_list[0],
    max_depth=3,
    verbose=True,
)

fm.to_csv('advanced_fm.csv')
fm.head()
```

The variable `es` holds the dataset:

[image]

Then, the `cutoff_time_list[0]` has a table which looks like this:

[image]

However, I get this error:
AttributeError: Cutoff time DataFrame must contain a column with either the same name as the target dataframe index or a column named "instance_id"
Even when the dataframe and the cut-off table both have an "engine_no" column. Why is this caused? I'm using the version `1.27.0` of `featuretools`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message here is really pointing you in the right direction. It says that the cutoff time dataframe must have a column with the same name as the index column of the target dataframe. In your example, you set the target dataframe to `RUL data`, but the index of that dataframe is set to the column named `index`. Since there is no column in the cutoff time dataframe named `index` you are getting this error.

Based on the example notebook you have linked, I think you really want to have `target_dataframe_name` set to the `normalRUL` dataframe, which has its index set as `engine_no`.

Comment: Yup that's correct, I was adapting the tutorial and at some point got confused with what I had to change. Thanks for the answer!